# Dojo tree grid shows ... for null valus

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Hi I am using Dojo tree grid for my application,

For null values, Dojo tree grid uses "..." . I need to show it as empty field. Help me how to avoid "..." in tree grid display?

Sorry i couldn't add screenshot. Bcoz i dont have enough reputation

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Can you provide a link to a jsfiddle with an example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am assuming you are using dojox/grid/TreeGrid.  You need a custom formatter function for your cells in the layout object you provide for the grid .  Check out the documentation for the cell formatter http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html.  In your formatter you need to check if the value is not what you want and return an empty string.

Comment: See the accepted answer for here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599497/how-to-add-a-blank-empty-row-to-the-enhancedgrid-which-is-binded-to-memorystore/26408476#26408476)